# Android UI Thread blocked in new Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, ui-thread, blocked

I'm working on a small Android game that handles canvas drawing on a working thread. After the game is over this thread should start the next activity, but somehow the UI thread seems to get blocked by starting a new function.

This is my games Main-Loop:

```
while(true)
    // Perform Ticks until the player makes a mistake
    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    if ((toDraw = rh.performTick()) == null) {
         lose();
         break;
     }
     _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(draw(toDraw,c));
}
```

The function `performTick()` processes the game logic and returns `null` when the game ends.  `draw()`does the rendering. Both Functions work perfect - the problem is `lose()`, which does nothing than starting a new Activity:

```
    protected void lose() {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(_context, MainMenu.class);
                _context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

When the Game ends, the new Activiy (MainMenu) starts normally but does not react on any touch events. There is no LogCat output and no Exception occuring. Even worse, `lose()`works normal when its called BEFORE the main loop starts.

I've been working on this for days now. I tried to start the Activity directly from the working Thread (without using a `Handler` in `lose()`) and searched the Internet for hours - nothing helps. It seems like the UI Thread is somehow blocked or caught in an infinite loop, and i have no idea how to fix this.

Everything is debugged on a Nexus 4 device.

Btw: `MainMenu.onCreate()` works normal when started another way.

Please help,
MA3o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't unlock the canvas when the if statement is true. Break will get you out of the while, leaving the canvas locked.

```
while(true)
    // Perform Ticks until the player makes a mistake
    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    if ((toDraw = rh.performTick()) == null) {
         lose();
         break;
     }

     // this line won't be executed whether the if statement above is true
     _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(draw(toDraw,c));
}
```

You should unlock inside the if statement also (before or after lose()).

Comment: That easy... Works fine, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead if `While(true)` you could have `While(myVar)` where `myVar` is a boolean that is true while game should be running and set to false when you call `lose()` In your case you continued to draw although you did not need to.

Comment: It won't continue to draw, because the break inside the if statement cancels the while.

Comment: Yep, i was commenting on what Ma3o wrote not yours, yours in completely right, my solution will run the '_surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(draw(toDraw,c));' once more after the user already lost which is probably not what he wanted.

Comment: Even if this would have fixed the problem, too (because the while loop would finish and unlocks the canvas again), the answer itself is wrong. The keyword `break;`is used to end a loop immediatly, independent of its normal behaviour, so the loop ends when `lose()`was called and the programm stops drawing